# Twitter json warning

Tags: json, google-chrome, twitter, counter

everyone. When I get tweets count like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='+ url +'&callback=?',function(data){
    return data.count;
});
```

Google Chrome shows this warning:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

I tried a lot of options, but can find right one. How can I remove this warning?

Comment: Real programmers don't listen to warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It's a JSONP request, so it *has* to be interpreted as a script. However, twitter is serving it up as JSON. Hence the MIME type mismatch.